# Register User provisioning app in Azure Gallery

Tags: azure, provisioning

I have created a SCIM enabled App. My only concern is User Provisioning.
Is it allowed to register the app in Azure App gallery without adding the functionality of SSO in the app?
I'm referring to this [document by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/howto-app-gallery-listing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would recommend both, but it is possible to build an Enterprise App with just provisioning and not SSO. It's something that would probably warrant a discussion on why that choice is being made, in order to ensure that the customer experience when using it is good.